# Is it possible to use java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation in JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit, instrumentation

Is it possible to use java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation in JUnit tests? I am using mockrunner to simulate a Servlet and want to measure the size of objects stored in a session

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, but not very straightforward.

The problem with using java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation is that you will ALWAYS need to use a JVM agent. 
A good introduction to JVM agents is available at http://www.javabeat.net/2012/06/introduction-to-java-agents/.

However, since your unit tests run in a jvm too, you can specify the agent as a JVM argument.

A memory reporting JVM agent for what you want to do, and ready for packaging, is available at https://github.com/jbellis/jamm. 
You can build it with either Maven or Ant.
In order to use it, you build it and then pass the following as a jvm argument when you start the unit test or unit test suite:

```
-javaagent:<path to>/jamm.jar
```

Within the unit tests, you can then instantiate the MemoryMeter and use it:

```
MemoryMeter meter = new MemoryMeter();
meter.measure(object);
meter.measureDeep(object);
meter.countChildren(object);
```